For a series RLC circuit, does the stored energy definition of the Q-factor give EXACTLY one over the fractional bandwidth?
I have read in several sources that for a resonator the stored energy definition of the Q-factor is "approximately" the reciprocal of the fractional bandwidth (with negligible error for Q greater than about ten).
However when I analyse a series RLC circuit driven by a voltage source, I get the two precisely the same with no error (in fact, I also get this for a parallel circuit driven by a current source).
Is this because this circuit is a special case, or am I overlooking something?
Outline workings:

resonance: the angular frequency \$\omega_0\$ at which \$X_C=-X_L\$. I obtain:
$$\omega_0=\frac{1}{\sqrt{LC}}$$
\$Q_0\$: the ratio of the peak stored energy to the mean energy dissipated per radian, at resonance. I obtain:
$$Q_0=\frac{1}{R}\sqrt{\frac{L}{C}}$$
half power points: the angular frequencies \$\omega_1, \omega_2\$ at which the power dissipated in the circuit is 50% of the peak at resonance. I obtain the condition for half power as:
$$\omega L-\frac{1}{\omega C}=\pm R$$
from the quadratic equation
$$\omega=\frac{1}{2L}\bigg(\pm R\pm\sqrt{R^2+4\tfrac{L}{C}}\bigg)$$
but as \$\sqrt{R^2+4\tfrac{L}{C}}>R\$, the positive solutions are:
$$
\begin{align}
\omega_1,\omega_2&=\frac{1}{2L}\bigg(\sqrt{R^2+4\tfrac{L}{C}}\pm R\bigg)\\
\implies\Delta{\omega} &= \frac{R}{L}
\end{align}
$$
fractional bandwidth: the difference between the half power points as a fraction of the resonant frequency. From the preceding:
$$\begin{align}
\frac{\Delta f}{f_0}=\frac{\Delta \omega}{\omega_0}&=\frac{R}{L}\sqrt{LC}\\
&=R\sqrt{\frac{C}{L}}\\
&=\frac{1}{Q_0}
\end{align}$$


My best guess is that it's due to different definitions of 'resonant frequency' (e.g. when the voltage across the capacitor peaks, etc). If so, then sources stating the assertion would do well to clarify this.

Having looked closely again at the algebra and also read some of the primary sources (e.g. Radio Engineering, F.E.Terman link), I'm satisfied that for straightforward series and parallel RLC circuits it holds without approximation, that:
$$
\frac{\Delta f}{f_0}=\frac{1}{Q_0},
$$
where the quantities are defined as above.
There is a caveat however: the Q-factor of the circuit must not change with frequency. In particular the value of R must not be a function of \$\omega\$; as would for instance be the case if you were modelling a capacitor with a constant \$Q_c\$.
